# html form updating mysql database

Tags: mysql, html, database, forms, jsp

i have created a html document shown below, however i am having trouble with the mysql coding to make the values from the form update my mysql database. Can anyone help me on how to go about this please?

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>

        <h1>Submit your notices below:</h1>

        <form name="messages" action="teacher1messages.jsp" method="POST"         enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <h1>Username:</h1>
        <input type="text" name="username" value="eg.cs09kkk1" />
            <h1>Date of notice:</h1>
            <input type="text" name="date" value="dd/mm/yy" />
            <h1>Notice:</h1>
            <textarea name="message1" rows="4" cols="20">
[Type your notices here]
            </textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
            <h1>Acknowledgment:</h1>
            <input type="text" name="acknowledgment" value="" />
        </form>


    </body>
</html>
```

this is the sql update coding i have tried however it just updates the table in my database as null null, rather than the  user input values

```
--%><sql:update var="messages" dataSource="jdbc/noticeboard">
    INSERT INTO messages (username, postedon, message, acknowledgment)
VALUES ('$_POST[username]','$_POST[date]','$_POST[message1]','$_POST[acknowledgment]')
</sql:update>
```

Comment: are you getting any error? paste content of teacher1messages.jsp page here..I think there u r righting the dao code

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "update your database?

Comment: action="teacher1messages.jsp does this part of the code have to be the page that my code is on? or do i need another page and another bit of code to make this work?

Comment: @ d_inevitable i want the details from the form to be inserted into the database as a new record, so when people post messages, i want a table of the messages they have posted.

Answer (score 0):

Having never used jsp this is probably wrong but isn't the correct syntax:

```
$_POST['username']
```

not

```
'$_POST[username]'
```

So your code becomes:

```
<sql:update var="messages" dataSource="jdbc/noticeboard">
    INSERT INTO messages (username, postedon, message, acknowledgment) VALUES ($_POST['username'],$_POST['date'],$_POST['message1'],$_POST['acknowledgment'])
</sql:update>
```

Comment: javax.servlet.ServletException: 
    INSERT INTO messages (username, postedon, message, acknowledgment) VALUES ($_POST['username'],$_POST['date'],$_POST['message1'],$_POST['acknowledgment'])
: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '['username'],$_POST['date'],$_POST['message1'],$_POST['acknowledgment'])' at line 1
it brings up that error. i need the actual values of the forms to be inputted because right now my database has $_POST[username] instead of their username.

Answer (score 0):

There's no `$_POST` in JSP, that probably is PHP. Try with `ServletRequest`'s [`getParameter()`  method](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter(java.lang.String)).

Comment: sorry, got misled with the `teacher1messages` and `Hello World` words

Answer (score 0):

Those `$_POST[parameterName]` are for PHP.
You are messing with PHP and JSP here. Your query should be :

```
<sql:update var="messages" dataSource="jdbc/noticeboard">
    INSERT INTO messages (username, postedon, message, acknowledgment)
        VALUES ('<%=request.getParameter("username")%>',
                '<%=request.getParameter("date")%>',
                '<%=request.getParameter("message1")%>',
                '<%=request.getParameter("acknowledgment")%>')
</sql:update>
```

`<%=request.getParameter("parameterName")%>` is used in JSP to print the value of `parameterName` parameter.